# Rails Nested JSON Include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to use `include` for my json response, which works great, but when I start to nest it, I'm getting a strange result

The `include` doesn't return the `gym` object. If I flip the order and put `trainer` last, that object doesn't get returned.

Am I missing something with my syntax ?

```
msg = {:requests => @customer_sessions.as_json(:include => [:session_coupon, :trainer => {:methods => [:rating, :completed_sessions_length, :following]}, :gym => {:methods => :rating}])}
format.json  { render :json => msg }
```

Comment: quick idea, try a hash instead of an array to :include. EG: `:include => {:one, :two, :three}`

Comment: @Rots I don't think that works, but I understand your idea. Hashes need a key value pair right ?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Was thinking more like this `:include {:trainer => {:methods => [:rating, :completed_sessions_length, :following]}, :gym => {:methods => :rating}}`

Answer (score 1):

Adding hashes worked for those interested

```
msg = {:status => "SUCCESS", :messages => "Requests Found", :requests => @customer_sessions.as_json(:include => [:session_coupon, {:trainer => {:methods => [:rating, :completed_sessions_length, :following]}}, {:gym => {:method => :rating}}])}
format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
```